# TypeError: RunCppShapeInference() takes exactly 5 arguments (6 given)

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, pre-trained-model

I am getting this error
TypeError: RunCppShapeInference() takes exactly 5 arguments (6 given)

while running the pretrained vgg16 net. Can anyone tell me what is the problem.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, 
ZeroPadding2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import cv2, numpy as np

def VGG_16(weights_path=None):
model = Sequential()
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1),input_shape=(3,224,224)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='softmax'))

if weights_path:
    model.load_weights(weights_path)

return model
```

if **name** == "**main**":
    img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('glass2.jpg'), (224, 224))

```
mean_pixel = [103.939, 116.779, 123.68]
img = img.astype(np.float32, copy=False)
for c in range(3):
    img[:, :, c] = img[:, :, c] - mean_pixel[c]
img = img.transpose((2, 0, 1))
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)

# Test pretrained model
model = VGG_16('vgg16_weights.h5')
sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy')
out = model.predict(img)
print (np.argmax(out))
```

I am having this error while creating the model
model = VGG_16('vgg16_weights.h5')

Comment: Post all relevant code here directly. Don't link to code. Apparently you're giving the wrong number of arguments to `RunCppShapeInference` though.

Comment: I am not directly calling the RunCppShapeInterference method. Is there any solution to this. @Carcigenicate

Comment: Find the stack trace of the error, figure out where the calling code is and find out why it's being given the wrong number of arguments.

Comment: you need to inspect the whole error message, the function is being called somewhere within scopes you do not directly see

Comment: plus your function VGG_16 needs to have the contents tab indented!